# C problem with fseek/ftell: Seems to return to the wrong position in a txt file

Tags: c

There is some very strange `fseek()` behaviour in my C program.
It reads a txt file of about 0.5 MB.
At some point in the code, the stream needs to return to a previous waypoint (stored using `ftell()`), but something goes wrong.

I extracted the relevant code in a smaller test program, which is shown below:

```c
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen(filename,"r");

//Skip to the line where I want to set my waypoint
for(long k = 0; k < 24914; k++)
    fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, fp);

//Set waypoint, skip some lines and go back
int pos = ftell(fp);
printf("location is %i = %i\n", pos, ftell(fp)); //output = "location is 192388 = 192388"
printf("line = %s", line);                     //output = "line = 126 1" (it is a graph, this represents an edge)

fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, fp);
printf("line = %s", line);                     //output = "line = 126 2"
printf("location is %i\n", ftell(fp));         //output = "location is 192396"

//Return to my old position/waypoint
fseek(fp, pos + 1, SEEK_SET); //+1 to skip \n (without +1 it would return an empty line)
printf("NEWlocation is %i = %i + 1\n", ftell(fp), pos);     //output = "NEWlocation is 192389 = 192388 + 1"

//Read again, expect "126 1" to be printed
fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, fp);
printf("line = %s\n", line);                       //output = "line = 126 64", which is about 60 lines further
printf("location is %i\n", ftell(fp));             //output = "location is 192398"
```

I am very confused about this behaviour.
I expect it to return to the waypoint, but it ends up approximately 60 lines further in the code.
I tried to look online for similar behaviour, but did not find anything apart from the possibility that the file is too large (but my file is <2GB).

For completeness, the  libraries I included are:

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 500
```

Comment: `ftell()` returns a `long`, not an `int`.

Comment: Thanks, it works (I can't believe I did this) Thank you very much for the quick response

Comment: For a text stream, you may `fseek()` only to a "position" previously returned by `ftell()`, and that position does not necessarily correlate with a file offset.  You may not `fseek` to `pos + 1`.  If you wish, however, you can read and discard one character after seeking.  Or before `ftell()`ing.

Comment: Okay thanks for the comment @JohnBollinger. It compiles just fine if I do this, but it does not matter if I put pos+1 or pos, do does it just ignore the +1?

Comment: I would expect it to compile, @DoubleDip.  I would also expect `x = sqrt(-1);` to compile under many circumstances.  That doesn't mean the code is correct.  That doesn't mean that it won't do what you expect under some circumstances, either, but even if it happens to do so, you are open to the code failing unexpectedly on a different machine, with a different input file, or under various other conditions that you might not expect to make a difference.

Comment: On POSIX, text streams are the same as binary streams. You may have trouble on MS Windows.

Comment: The easiest way to deal with the issue is to use binary mode exclusively, and convert line endings explicitly. It is more portable this way, meaning your code can run on *ix and deal with ms-dos files with no problem.